# Bind elements to 2 different columns in a Z way

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I have a mainview with a grid divided into two columns.

The issue is that I have an organized list of view models ( user controls with a textbox with different scopes ) that is created dynamically, and I want to display them in a Z way.
I.e: from left to right, top to bottom ( see image )

[image]

At the moment i'm using something like the code above, dividing the list in the viewmodel into two different lists according to the element index.

```
<Grid>
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

<Stackpanel Grid.Column=0>
  <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="EvenElements">
        <Border>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" />
        </Border>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</Stackpanel> 

<Stackpanel Grid.Column=1>
  <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="OddElements">
        <Border>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" />
        </Border>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</Stackpanel> 
</Grid>
```

Is there a way to do it in a **single binding** style? I don't want to join the textboxes input later because the index matters, and the code doesn't look that clean in that way. Thank you

Comment: Have you tried using WrapPanel control or an UniformGrid ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your issue correctly, you could use an `UniformGrid` as the `ItemsPanel` of the `ItemsControl`:

```
<ItemsControl>
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <UniformGrid Columns="2" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
</ItemsControl>
```

Comment: Sweet. Worked like a charm.